# Why wont my javascript affect bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason bootstrap is not allowing me to set the interval time in js.

I'm using Middleman to serve my static website to localhost and I cant seem to get the js to affect the carousel from bootstrap. I loaded the bootstrap and my custom js like this

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Save Rosie
    %meta{charset: "utf-8"}/
    / Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame
    %meta{content: "IE=edge,chrome=1", "http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible"}/
    / Use title if it's in the page YAML frontmatter
    = stylesheet_link_tag "fonts", "all", "bootstrap"
    = javascript_include_tag  "jquery-1.11.0.min", "all", "bootstrap"
  %body{class: page_classes}
    = yield
```

the carousel is fully functional

```
.carousel.slide{ "data-ride" => "carousel" }
      .carousel-inner
        .item.active
          %img{ :src => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rosiesdonations/Rosie1.png', :alt => "Rosie Picture one" }
        .item
          %img{ :src => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rosiesdonations/Rosie2.jpg', :alt => "Rosie Picture two" }
        .item
          %img{ :src => 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/rosiesdonations/Rosie3.jpg', :alt => "Rosie Picture three" }
```

but when I call

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
})
```

in all.js it doesn't switch at 2seconds but rather the default 5.

Looking there is an error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel'

I tried loading the bootstrap first but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the DOM ready when you set the interval?

Comment: Your code must be inside a block such as `$(document).ready(function(){ ...your code... });`

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't know this, Edit its still not changing defaults

Answer (score 2):

In your scripts `bootstrap.js` must be before `all.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be a problem, but try to set the first Carousel slide item with `class="active"` and then initialize the js for the carousel in this way:

```
$(function(){
 $('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
 });
});
```

Comment: Tried this to but im still getting  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel'

Comment: Download the carousel.js from [here](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.3/docs/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js) and then load it in your code.

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: Bootstrap version 3. My carousel is working fine ince it has the same class names, just when I try to actually use it in javascript it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh now this should help for sure. Assign one `id` to your carousel and then try using ` $('#your-carousel-id').carousel({ interval: 2000}); `